# Options for deploying mobile site

Tags: web-applications, mobile, web, lamp

So I have a site 'somesite.com', and now I want to deploy a mobile version of the same. The development is done, and the code base is common between the desktop version and the mobile version. Major changes are in smarty templates; the PHP code has if else statements to display the appropriate template. The templates for desktop and mobile site are in completely different files.

I am considering the following alternatives, and would much appreciate your help in making an informed decision about this.

1. Serve mobile site and desktop site out of single site; thesomesite.com itself. The code can handle it without any problem. 
   pros - I deploy the code only to one place. No admin hassles for me. 
   cons - ??. Is it a bad practice? I see most sites maintain a different URL for mobile site.
2. Serve mobile site out of a new domain - somesite.mobi
   pros - ??. Are there any pros to this? Like improved SEO? 
   cons - I end up deploying the exact same code to two different locations
3. Serve mobile site out of a subdomain - m.somesite.com
   pros - ??
   cons - same as under #2 above.

Thanks much for your inputs.

-Amit

Comment: i'm no absolute expert on this, but we're doing our tests and getting some results out of them. i bet your different templates already handle a different css for the different media (if not, they should). we're serving the mobile version from a mobi.oursite.com domain. code is deployed alltogheter, and we use nginx to serve different media based on their agent

Comment: Yes the CSS if different, and yes we check the agent to identify mobiles. My question is why create a sub domain site at all? why create mobi.oursite.com? Why not serve out of oursite.com itself?

Comment: then how you want to deploy your website is all up to you. I suggest you read something http://www.onbile.com/info/seo-domain-structure-on-mobile-devices/ here. They say that an hybrid combination of the two is the best choice.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo. Thank you for the article. The article recommends the hybrid approach - maintain a single web site. May be that is what I would use.

Comment: that's probably for the best, if you're not serving too different things :)